# Rails saving data to model that has multiple has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I have a product model that looks like

```
belongs_to :seller
has_many :coupons
```

And coupon model that looks like

```
belongs_to :seller
belongs_to :product
```

And in my Products controller I use

```
@seller = current_user
@coupon = @seller.coupons.create(params[:coupon])
```

to create the coupons for the seller

While the coupon is being created, I need to associate it with the product too, i.e When a new coupon is created it should be saved for the seller AS WELL AS for the product.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work if `params[:coupon]` contains a `product_id`.

Answer (score 0):

you can create like:

```
@coupon = @seller.coupons.create(params[:coupon], product_id: @product.id)
```